# Why do I get "expected class or object definition" when defining a type in scala?

Tags: scala, slick

If I write something like this (to define Slick tables as per [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/orm-to-slick.html)):

```
type UserIdentity = (String, String)
class UserIdentity(tag: Tag){
...
}
```

I get a compile error: "expected class or object definition" pointing to the `type` declaration. Why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't define type aliases outside of a class, trait, or object definition.

If you want a type alias available at the package level (so you don't have to explicitly import it), the easiest way around this to define a [package object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html), which has the same name as a package and allows you to define anything inside of it, including type aliases.

So if you have a `foo.bar`package and you wish to add a type alias, do this:

```
package foo

package object bar {
  type UserIdentity = (String, String)
}

//in another file
package foo.bar
val x: UserIdentity = ...
```